# What can I do to finish, because I dont know how I can get the jan has ... days a month, instead of jan is not a correct month name

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter a year and
        // the first three letter of a month name
        System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
        String month = input.next();

        // Test for leap year
        boolean leapYear = 
            ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);

        // Display the number of day in the month
        System.out.print(month + " " + year + " has ");
        
        if ( month.equals("Jan") || month.equals("Mar") || 
              month.equals("May") || month.equals("Jul") ||
              month.equals("Aug") || month.equals("Oct") ||
              month.equals("Dec"))
            System.out.print(31 + " days");
        else if (month.equals("Apr") || month.equals("Jun") || 
            month.equals("Sep") || month.equals("Nov"))
            System.out.print(30 + " days");
        else if (month.equals("Feb"));
            System.out.print(((leapYear) ? 29 : 28) + " days"); 
        else 
           System.out.print(month + " is not a correct month name");
    }
}
```

I tried to add the last sentence to fix the problem but it dont work
Write a program that prompts the user to enter the year and the first three letters of a month name (with the first letter in uppercase) and displays the number of days in the month. If the input for the month is incorrect, display a message as presented in the following sample runs:

Enter a year: 2001 Enter a month: Jan Jan 2001 has 31 days

Enter a year: 2016 Enter a month: jan jan is not a correct month name
I tried to understand that I can use this sentence because I had declare that Jan, Feb,etc. having the capital letter but I my point is that when I enter other name or the name of the month that do not have the capital letter is the wrong answer and I will have the answer as the last sentence of the code.

Comment: `equals()` is case sensitive, perhaps you want `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead?

Comment: Also you have a typo there, `else if (month.equals("Feb"));` shouldn't have a semicolon at the end. The code won't even compile with the dangling else. Your IDE should have an autoformatting and it would've put the tabbing out of whack when you're typing it, and let you know the last else is invalid when you type it.

Comment: If this is schoolwork rather than real work, you should mention that fact in your Question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce because I cannot compile your code. I get “'else' without 'if'” on your last `else` because of the spurious semicolon that @Martheen mentioned. Also please surround the inner statements in if-else-if with curly braces as the code conventions say, it will make it easier for us to read and decipher your code.

Comment: If this is for an exercise, it’s a fine exercise. For production code one would not write that logic oneself but would leave to the standard library to know how many days there are in a month. There is a `YearMonth` class for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I tried to add the last sentence to fix the problem but it dont work ..."*

The syntax is incorrect.

This *else-if* should not end with a `;`.

```java
else if (month.equals("Feb"));
```

Utilize a *switch statement*.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompt the user to enter a year and
// the first three letter of a month name
System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
int year = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
String month = input.next();

// Test for leap year
boolean leapYear =
    ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);

// Display the number of day in the month
System.out.print(month + " " + year + " has ");

int days = switch (month) {
    case "Jan", "Mar", "May", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Dec" -> 31;
    case "Apr", "Jun", "Sep", "Nov" -> 30;
    case "Feb" -> leapYear ? 29 : 28;
    default -> 0;
};
if (days != 0) System.out.println(days  + " days");
else System.out.println(month + " is not a correct month name");
```

Comment: TIL Java 14 has a new switch syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reimplementing the logic, I would use [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) to get the last day of the month. And you could keep a `Map<String, Integer>` to map between the month name and the month number. Also, you need to use a case-insensitive comparison (or convert to all lower or all upper case). Something like,

```
static Map<String, Integer> MONTH_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    String[] months = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY",
            "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        MONTH_MAP.put(months[i], i + 1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter a year and
    // the first three letter of a month name
    System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
    String month = input.next();
    int mon = MONTH_MAP.getOrDefault(month.toUpperCase(), 0);
    if (mon > 0) {
        int days = java.time.YearMonth.of(year, mon)
                .atEndOfMonth().getDayOfMonth();
        System.out.println(days);
    } else {
        System.out.println(month + " is not a correct month name");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're allowed to use the classes in `java.time`, you may as well just use a `DateTimeFormatter` to look up the month name.  However, one of the problems about being a programming teacher is thinking up exercises that are simple enough for the students to grasp all the required concepts, but for which the solution doesn't already exist in some library somewhere, or some JDK package, that someone is going to tell the students about.

Comment: Thanks man, but can you show me how to deal with this situation right now, I dont have any clue on dealing with it